# Is it possible to have two phones (one of which an iPhone) on the same number without changing the SIM card?

Tags: iphone, sim

I have always wondered whether it was possible to use the same phone number on an "emergency phone" in case the main one gets lost.

Comment: google voice lets your route phone communications in all sorts of ways. If you get a google voice number, you can give that out and then have calls go to both of your phones (or one and switch them over if the first is stolen). I don't really use GVoice that much anymore, but if I had lots of phones to juggle, I would.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

Yes it is possible. I think they developed this for the fixed car-phones. Some providers support 2 simcards with the same number. How it works:

- The phone that had a connection and some communication to the cell-tower last will be the primary phone.
- When you make a call, that phone becomes the primary phone.
- When you change locations (change cell-tower), that will be your primary phone.
- If your primary phone is not on the network, your secondary phone will become the primary phone.

The primary phone is the only phone that can receive calls. Both phones can call.
Ask your provider for more info.

This is based on my experience (Vodafone, Netherlands). And I am sure there are better descriptions out there ;)

Comment: I had never heard of this before. Now I have! Thanks.

Comment: @nekomatic: If you think the answer is useful, you can up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

I was always under the impression that only one SIM card at a time could be registered to any given phone number, but another answer suggests otherwise.

If you lose your phone and contact your network to report it missing then it would be technically possible for them to transfer your number to a different SIM card that you already possessed on the same network, but it would be a matter of their policy whether they were willing to do that. Obviously they would be able to transfer your number to a *new* SIM card that they would send out to you, but you'd have to wait to receive it and I'm sure they would make a charge for this.

It should be possible to set up call diversion to a different phone number if your phone is lost, but again this depends on whether your network chooses to offer the service - you can normally do this from the phone number you are diverting calls from but obviously in the situation you suggest you wouldn't have that phone.

This is really a question to ask your network as the answer will come down to what they are able or willing to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Your cellphone company probably has a way to forward your calls. For example AT&T (who I use) says that [you need to call them](http://www.att.com/esupport/article.jsp?sid=53957&cv=820) to forward your number to another phone.

Phone companies use to offer the ability to ring multiple phones simultaneously or in rotation, but I don't see that AT&T offers this. (Although maybe they do offer it in business plans.)

Other options are to use a service like [Line2](https://www.line2.com) or [SendHub](https://www.sendhub.com) however these would be expensive options if you don't need their other services.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

Strictly the phone does not have a number. It has an International Mobile Subscriber Identity or **IMSI** which serves to identify the SIM to the network. These must be globally unique.

The "number" which people call is the **MSISDN**.

The network uses the IMSI to locate and communicate with the phone and the Home Location Register **HLR** (which is a database) to translate between MSISDN and IMSI.

When I last worked as a mobile network planner, I was not aware of any standard way of having a relationship between MSISDN and multiple IMSI, but it is trivial to change which IMSI is related to a MSISDN. This is how carriers can change your SIM and the basis of Mobile Number Portability.

I have not kept up with the latest standards, but the only way you could find out is to contact your network operator.

As mentioned by others you could have 2 subscriptions, and forward a single MSISDN to the 2nd backup service, but this usually involves additional call charges.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible since it is available service over seas.

"It used to be that you had to go overseas to see and enjoy the latest in mobile phone technology. The playing field has certainly leveled, but there are still some practices that have yet to be adopted by the United States. One such practice is the ability for a user to have more than one SIM card for one mobile phone number." Read More here http://www.geek.com/mobile/do-you-want-two-sim-cards-for-one-phone-number-1024011/

Answer (score 0):

A number of providers (e.g. ATT's [NumberSync](https://www.att.com/shop/wireless/features/numbersync.html), Telstra's ['One Number'](http://www.zdnet.com/article/telstra-launches-telstra-one-number-esim-technology/)) are offering this service now and with the advent of cellular enabled Things (e.g.  Apple Watch 3, Samsung Gear S2 etc) it seems it's only going to grow - see [Apple's list of supported cellular](https://www.apple.com/watch/cellular/) carriers for their Watch 3. Though there seem to be some limitations as to which devices are compatible with these services. It also seems that some are relying on OS based services (e.g. like Facetime) but others may use VoLTE, or WiFi-Calling...